# Is there an affective state of knowledge or belief?

Tags: knowledge, belief, emotions

Is there an affective state of knowledge or belief? Can I affectively or emotionally know that my wife is having an affair or that I am not the father of my children, but not be able to justify to myself or anyone else, even the claim that I might believe it? I fear that, if so, I am condemned to hell itself, and will need to say my prayers at least. How morally etc. salient is it?

Take the following example. It is late at night and I am walking home alone. I hear a sound, and, though I looked around and saw no-one and believe I am still alone, I am gripped by the sense of being followed by god knows who. "You there!" I shout "I will kill you if you don't go away", unsure of why I do. Then I laugh and carry on my way, certain that I have not deliberately threatened anyone. Have I? What if there was someone there?

Comment: Aquinas and other theologians talked about "affective knowledge" of God, and sometimes it is applied to moral values, see [Mulligan](https://www.fil.lu.se/hommageawlodek/site/papper/MulliganKevin.pdf). But the idea that emotions can support ordinary factual knowledge is rather dubious. They can *explain* why a subject holds some factual belief (true or false), but hardly contribute to *justifying* it, it is more in the territory of cognitive biases than cognitive faculties.

Comment: i wonder what insight bipolar ppl might shed on this. thanks for the clear comment, even if has only settled my worry rather than resolved it ha @Conifold can you summarise mulligan for me? i suppose that i may know i value something and have acted on that, but i'm unsure about intent etc.

Comment: i think the question about my moral responsibility just hinges on whether we need at least the outline of knowledge of what is happening, for it. i can't see it being legally intent, cos that does/should operate independently of whether anyone is there, right?

Comment: no that can't be right.

Comment: Apparently no for most people as shown by the lack of affective interest of views stats so far compared with many other questions in this site...

Comment: i found [this](https://philarchive.org/archive/ANDDHA) @Conifold affective belief in religion involves affective valuing due to salvific potential, and loyalty/trust when called to mind