# Is belief nothing but a feeling of certainty about what something means?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language, semantics, social-epistemology

Or to rephrase, can beliefs also be shaped by doubts and intuitions?

Comment: There are many factors which shape our beliefs. The first factor is our social upbringing. Another factor are all forms of wishful thinking. Also sometimes, the overwhelming feeling of certainty and the trust into one’s strong intuition. But these factors do not ensure that our beliefs are correct. One has to always check one's beliefs by looking over the rim of one’s tea cup and by critical questioning.

Comment: Most of our beliefs do not involve certainty at all.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA but we don't know that. We believe them as true.

Comment: [SEP, Belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief):"*Most contemporary philosophers characterize belief as a “propositional attitude”... A propositional attitude, then, is the mental state of having some attitude, stance, take, or opinion about a proposition.*" An attitude might be accompanied by feelings, or it might not. One might be ready to act on some proposition (i.e. believe in it) not only without any feelings, but even without conscious acknowledgement, let alone reflection on its truth. Most beliefs are what they call "implicit".

Comment: **As always in Philosophy, this depends on the definition**. In the context of Bayesian Networks, for example, a belief has a very strict mathematical meaning. And nothing to do with feelings, whatsoever.

Comment: This is a great question which hints at the very difficult distinction between knowledge and belief and at the ever perilous (but needed) self-assessment of our own thinking. This difficulty is unfortunately not addressed enough in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hot take:
The word "believe" [originally meant](https://www.google.com/search?q=believe%20word%20origin) ["be glad", or "be in love with"](https://tybennett.com/the-true-definition-of-belief/), and its root word *lief* is [cognate with our word "love"](https://www.google.com/search?q=lief%20word%20origin).

The word "belief" clearly means something different than intellectual assent or conjectural certainty.
It may actually be a (more or less mathematical) *derivative* of intellectual assent.
That is, what we love, we tend to be more accepting of. What we do not love, we tend to find reasons to withdraw our assent from.
What we love, we find surety in, and our certainty increases the dearer a price we pay to know what is true.

In terms of rational update of belief in the presence of evidence, belief is objectively subjective, in that it is not *necessarily* bound to correspond to what is true, even when we think we have a high level of confidence in something, as in the following simulation, where an observer has held close to 90% confidence in a false conclusion.
[image: High positive confidence in a falsehood arrived at through iterative application of Bayes' Rule, even with correct and exactly estimated likelihood and marginal]
You can play with the simulator and the true positive and true negative rates here:
[Interactive Bayes Rule Simulator](https://codepen.io/seth-stewart/pen/BaaExLG)

Confidence is therefore not in itself demonstrative of understanding of truth. Divine knowledge would permit the formation of infallible certainty, by the simple syllogism that if one obtains knowledge from a Being that knows the thing and cannot lie it follows that proper and certain knowledge has been conveyed. But that is an expression of knowledge rather than belief.

Going with the edifying etymology over modern concepts, belief is and always will be a choice to love an idea irrespective of how or whether others esteem it, and that love has a tendency to increase intellectual assent and confidence over time.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152096/discussion-on-answer-by-pygosceles-is-belief-nothing-but-a-feeling-of-certainty); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 6):

We haven't seen what is inside a black hole, and almost certainly never will, but we can have beliefs about what is there.  Those beliefs are likely to be based on theories about reality that we have developed by astronomical observations and e.g. particle physics experiments.  I'd say that is more than a feeling of certainty about what exists.  As @MauroAllegranza points out, it isn't necessarily all that certain, and it is more than just feeling - it is logical reasoning about evidence (and consilience with other theories).  There are many ways in which we can form beliefs.

Comment: I would say that in your example it is a reasonable application of the Occam's razor principle to extrapolate our knowledge from our observations to unobservable areas. What is inside a black hole are also just hypotheses (like all the physics). I would not call it a belief.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong most of philosophy seems to be a waste of time quibbling about the meanings of words when the ambiguity is easily handled in everyday life.  In this case, the first definition I found for "belief" was "an acceptance that something exists or is true, especially one without proof."  Our views on the insides of black holes, formed via science, fall perfectly into that definition.  N.B. science is not about proof anyway, just reduction to the best explanation.

Comment: All beliefs/views/ideas about things we can't sense are going to be extrapolations of our knowledge from our observations to unobservable areas, what else do we have to go on (c.f. Kant?).  The problem with Occam's razor is that we might disagree on what we regard as simple or parsimonious.

Answer (score 6):

You can believe something without being certain. You probably believe many things you aren't certain of.

There are various philosophies for dealing with uncertainty, such as Bayesianism, which gives all beliefs a "credence", a % chance of being true, and discusses how those percents change with new information.

Answer (score 6):

This has come up before, whether belief is an [affective state](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/107589/is-there-an-affective-state-of-knowledge-or-belief)

In my experience, as a recovering paranoid schizoprhenic, no it is not an affective state. Rather, it is the exact opposite, an abstraction from them, a bit like the personal narrative of feeling and emotion, but perhaps working in tandem or struggling with those.

Answer (score 4):

Reductionism, that is, the desire to reduce one thing to another, is usually wrong. Belief is what it is and isn't anything else. It has aspects related to a feeling of certainty. It also  has aspects related to a disposition to agree to certain propositions. It also has aspects related to mental states. Which one it seems most like depends on what aspects you emphasize.

Comment: While Ive upvoted this, the first sentence is way too strong as stated. There would be no philosophy, science, or general discussions if all discussions that explain one thing in terms of another were wrong. I'd suggest changing *usually* to *often*

Answer (score 2):

Belief is a choice.

When evidence and logic and reason support conclusion, we can conclude.

When evidence and logic and reason are insufficient to support doing allow conclusion, but we wish to believe anyways, we make that choice - to 'believe'.

Belief sidesteps that requirement.  Denecessitates evidence, reason, ration, logic.  Faith doesn't require them.

Belief is a choice.  We choose our beliefs.  If we have any.

EDIT Mar 12th, 1:40am EST. ------>

I didn't go to Stanford.  They have an opinion on "[belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/)".  Someone provided the link.  (thx).  I didn't read it all.  Read enough.  Got to this term:

- "Mundane beliefs"

And some examples... "Stanford" says this:

> Many of the things we believe, in the relevant sense, are quite mundane: that we have heads, that it’s the 21st century, that a coffee mug is on the desk. Forming beliefs is thus one of the most basic and important features of the mind, and the concept of belief plays a crucial role in both philosophy of mind and epistemology.

So I should be clear my answer is not addressing "mundane beliefs" as I didn't think the question was asking about mundane beliefs.  Perhaps it was?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152000/discussion-on-answer-by-alistair-riddoch-is-belief-nothing-but-a-feeling-of-cert); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

A [belief](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/) is commonly understood to refer to "whenever we take something to be the case or regard it as true".

Correspondingly, a common definition of [knowledge](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/knowledge-analysis/#KnowJustTrueBeli) is "justified true belief".

Your beliefs can have varying levels of certainty, based on how well evidence and argument supports a particular conclusion.

And yes, beliefs can certainly be affected by doubts and intuitions.

---

Colloquially, "believe" might also be used when one has low confidence, or when one trusts or hopes something is the case. "I believe I saw this" is typically interpreted as you being less sure than when you say merely "I saw this".